# I am unable to redirect user in Yii after login

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am new to Yii so i decided to write a simple login script just to put to test what i have learnt so far.

For some reasons my code doesn't work as it should.

Ideally if username and password exist, it ought to redirect to the index view and also and if it doesn't exist it ought to redirect to the login view.

If username and password exist it redirects as it ought to and it also shows the right session value but if username and password doesn't exist i also get the same result.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Users;
use Yii;

class UsersController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $model = new users();
        return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new Users();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                // form inputs are valid, do something here
               $request = Yii::$app->request;
               $form_values = $request->post('Users');
               //var_dump($form_values['email']); exit;
               //echo $form_values['email'];
               if($model !==NULL){
                    $model = $model->doLogin($form_values['email'],$form_values['password']);
                    $session = Yii::$app->session;
                    $session->setFlash('login', 'Login succesful.');
                    return $this->render('index', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
                }

                elseif($model === NULL){

                    $session = Yii::$app->session;
                    $session->setFlash('login', 'Invalid Login.');
                    return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your condition does not make sense and your `else` branch is a dead code.

First you're initializing `$model` variable:

```
$model = new Users();
```

Then your testing if it is not `null`:

```
if($model !==NULL){
```

Which will **always** return `true` since you already initialized this variable to contain `Users` model, there is no chance it will be `null`. You should probably have something like this:

```
class UsersController extends \yii\web\Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = Users::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionLogin() {
        $model = new Users();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('login', 'Login successful.');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And handle login (validating username and password) in `Users::login()` method. See example in [basic application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/a0095a0bee542763c4c39fb273c407b03595d466/models/LoginForm.php).

Comment: Okay @rob006 please how is my else branch a dead code?  i need to have an because i need to let the user know if login is not successfull.

Comment: @Chi your else is a dead code because if the `$model===NULL` then it would never pass the `$model->load()` and will throw an exception, and hence it is never executed

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam i made an update to my action Login, this is what i currently have:

Comment: @Chi you can use this answer posted by roob006 it should work correctly in your case

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i might be wrong but i cant see anywhere he addressed the case if  user does not exist. If user does not exist it should also give an error.

Comment: @Chi it would load the view in that case with model errors which would be relevant to the wrong username or password